# identifying a Chrome webpage

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I would like to see if I have active Chrome, but not in other webpage but in a specific page.

If I use

```
IfWinExist ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

the script will find ALSO Chrome opened with other webpages, and I don't want that.

What should I do?

Comment: It would certainly help if you provided the webpage you're referring to.

Comment: this is the webpage I was referring  http://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/

Comment: How about checking for the actual window title?

Comment: Which would it be the script?

Comment: Have a look at the [IfWinActive docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure i quite understood what do you want to achieve but i once wrote a script to loop through all Chrome tabs, here is a slightly adjusted so it will go through all tabs and activate the one you want:

```
^!Space::
{
    IsSiteOpen()
    return
}

IsSiteOpen()
{
    Global TabTitleExist
    TabTitle = autohotkey
    SetTitleMatchMode 2
    IfWinExist, %TabTitle%
    {
        WinActivate, %TabTitle%
        WinMinimize, %TabTitle%
        MsgBox, 64, %TabTitle%, It is open
        return
    }

    LoopChromeTabs(TabTitle)
    if (TabTitleExist = 1)
    {
        WinActivate, %TabTitle%
        WinMinimize, %TabTitle%
        MsgBox, 64, %TabTitle%, It is open
        return
    }
    return
    }


    LoopChromeTabs(TabTitle)
    {
    Global TabTitleExist
    IfWinExist, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    {
    ; Get current open tab title
    WinGetTitle, FirstTitle

; Go through all open tabs and find the tab we are looking for or quit
Loop
{
    WinActivate ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Send ^{Tab}
    WinGetTitle, CurrentTitle

    ; After we changed tab have we found our tab?
    IfWinExist, %TabTitle%
    {
        TabTitleExist = 1
        break
    }

    ; We went through all tabs and we should stop there
    If (FirstTitle = CurrentTitle)
        break
    }
 }
}
```

https://github.com/ilirb/ahk-scripts/blob/master/executable/source/GoogleMusicRemote.ahk